# How can I resolve java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused error

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, amazon-emr

I have a spark program that writes messages to another kafka topic and writes checkpoints locally to the HDFS system

```
val query = kafkaDf.writeStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",conf.getString("bootstrap.servers")).option("topic","RTA-ALERT").option("checkpointLocation","hdfs://localhost:9000/user/checkpoint8").option("failOnDataLoss", "false").start()
```

These are the contents of core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

This works fine on my IDE. However when I package it as a jar an run it on an EMR cluster. I get the following error.

```
Call From ip-xxx-xx-xx-86/xxx.xx.xx.86 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

These are contents of core-site.xml on the master node of my EMR cluster

```
 <property>
    <!-- URI of NN. Fully qualified. No IP.-->
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://ip-xxx-xx-xx-86.ec2.internal:8020</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: In checkpointLocation you have hardcoded localhost:9000, check that once

Comment: your query has a hardcoded `localhost:9000` in it.

Comment: Use location as `hdfs:///user/checkpoint8` as core site already has fs.defaultFS config which contains namenode address.

Comment: @Srinivas Why does hardcoding localhost:9000 create a problem?What is the alternative?

Comment: @SašaZejnilović Why does hardcoding localhost:9000 create a problem?What is the alternative?

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti Changing the location  to hdfs:///user/checkpoint8  throws an error when I run it on my IDE

Comment: When you run it from IDE. I guess that's on your local machine. From there you have to fully specify name node i.e. `hdfs://ip-xxx-xx-xx-86.ec2.internal:8020/user/checkpoint8`. But when you run this from EMR masterNode itself you don’t have specify the namenode address [`hdfs:///user/checkpoint8` this should work. please be midful about 3 `/`]. It will automatically pickup whatever is the value of `fs.defaultFS`

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti Does your response work regardless of the mode the spark program is running in i.e client or cluster